# Can I buy gold from the cash auction house?

Tags: diablo-iii

I know you can buy equipment for real money in the cash auction house. Can you also just buy straight gold?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Blizzard Auction House FAQ](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/services/auction-house/info#q16) states:

> **Can we buy gold from the currency-based auction house?**
>
> Players will be able to buy and sell gold through the currency-based auction house at whatever the current market price is, as established by the player community.

Comment: Checked for source.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Gold will be treated as a commodity in the currency based auction house.

Comment: Does this effectively put grey market gold sales out of business?

Comment: @EBongo Not even close.  First of all, the grey market will be able to claim lower prices since they don't have to cover the 15% Blizzard cut.  Second of all, players whose home region is not Americas cannot use the Americas RMAH.  But you can be sure they'll sell items on the gold AH and then use the grey market to turn that gold into cash.